# Problem with mysql unicode

Tags: mysql, unicode, export

I have just imported mysql table from my live server to a local server.
But all the quotes and some special character have changed to `' ? '`.
And I don't have backup. Can anyone help me recover it.

Comment: What exactly has changed to what? What character set does the database have? Needs more info.

Comment: I doubt it - if you've lost the data then I don't think you can reliably automatically construct it back. You could search / replace common patterns, e.g. "pr?s de" to "près de" if this was French. But have you definitely lost the data? Could it be that the client you're using on the local server just isn't displaying them?

Comment: ya i lost the data , and too i don't know what the character was there before

Comment: isn't the table still in your live server? you might consider that as a backup, re fetch it

Comment: i have it in live server , but the special character has changed to ?

Comment: What is the special character that has changed to a question mark? Please show a screen shot of the actual data as it is meant to appear.

Comment: You said you have imported the data from live server to local server. Why the data on live server changed?

Answer (score 0):

Change your DB's CHARACTER SET to utf8 and reimport your table from the live server, that might fix it.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDb CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

**EDIT:**

You might also need to change the table `CHARSET` before importing it back to your local DB.
Open your `.sql` file and change the `CHARSET`. For example:

`ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;`

to

`ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;`

but ONLY change the `CHARSET` nothing else

Comment: i can't do this i don't have the back up

Comment: @user737767 re fetch your table from the live server

Answer (score 0):

use the below msqli code:

```html
masqli_set_charset(your_databse_connection,"utf")
```